# Android extends Application and make an instance of it

Tags: android, extend

I'm tried following code:-

```
public class LocationApplication extends Application {

public LocationInfo locationInfo;
public int myInt;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   }
}

public int getInt(){  
    someMethod(context);
    return myInt;
   }
}
```

Later in some other activity I have to get myInt that is in LocationApplication class. Note that I cannot make myInt static. So somehow I have to have an instance of LocationApplication class. So how do I make an instance of LocationApplication that is initialized by framework call chain earlier (means that onCreate() was called by framework).

Any other suggestion to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, when subclassing the `Application` class, you'll have to tell the framework that you'd like to use you that. The framework will keep only 1 instance of your `Application` subclass You do that by adding the following attribute to the `application` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name="com.example.android.LocationApplication"
```

Replace the `com.example.android` with your own packageId.

Your manifest could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android" >

    <application
        android:name="com.example.android.LocationApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Omitted the rest of the XML -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Next, in your `Activity` (or anything that extends from `Context`), you call `getApplication()`. Cast that to `LocationApplication` and you have access to your `Application` object.

That might look like this in your case:

```
// In your Activity (or anything that extends Context)
LocationApplication application = (LocationApplication) getApplication();
int value = application.getInt()
```

Comment: Let's immagine that some how I made class LocationApplication member public static int myInt; Can I get directly LocationApplication.myInt? Instead of calling  LocationApplication application = (LocationApplication) getApplication(); application.myInt? Or it is recommended to get it by calling  getApplication() always

Comment: As the framework manages the instance of `LocationApplication`, I recommend to always access the instance via `getApplication()`. You can read more about the `Application` class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

Make the Application class static and get a reference to that.

e.g.

```
public class LocationApplication extends Application {

    private static LocationApplication instance;

    private int myInt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static LocationApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


    public int getInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

}
```

then from your code, access the methods like this:

```
int TheInt= LocationApplication.getInstance().getInt();
```

You can call this from ANYWHERE in your code not just where you can call getApplication()

You will need to register the class in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

How to make an instance of Application class?

Inside the manifest file

```
<application android:name="fully qualified name of your application class"
 .............................
 ............................../>
```

By Declaring The class which extends Application class in manifest file like this, Instance of your customized applocation class will be created, Now when you want to access your application class
Inside an Activity you can simply,

```
MyApplication mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
```

now you can call getInt on the mApplication.